# Are navigation properties read each time they are accessed? (EF4.1)

Tags: entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am using EF 4.1, with POCOs which are lazy loaded.

Some sample queries that I run:

```
var discountsCount = product.Discounts.Count();  
var currentDiscountsCount = product.Discounts.Count(d=>d.IsCurrent);  
var expiredDiscountsCount = product.Discounts.Count(d=>d.IsExpired);
```

What I'd like to know, is whether my queries make sense, or are poorly performant:

Am I hitting the database each time, or will the results come from cached data in the DbContext?

Is it okay to access the navigation properties "from scratch" each time, as above, or should I be caching them and then performing more queries on them, for example:

```
var discounts = product.Discounts;  
var current = discounts.Count(d=>d.IsCurrent);  
var expired = discounts.Count(d=>d.Expired);
```

What about a complicated case like below, does it pull the whole collection and then perform local operations on it, or does it construct a specialised SQL query which means that I cannot reuse the results to avoid hitting the database again:

```
var chained = discounts.OrderBy(d=>d.CreationDate).Where(d=>d.CreationDate < DateTime.Now).Count();
```

Thanks for the advice!

**EDIT based on comments below**

So once I call a navigation property (which is a collection), it will load the entire object graph. But what if I filtered that collection using `.Count(d=>d...)` or `Select(d=>d...)` or `Min(d=>d...)`, etc. Does it load the entire graph as well, or only the final data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`product.Discounts` (or any other navigation collection) isn't an `IQueryable` but only an `IEnumerable`. LINQ operations you perform on `product.Discounts` will never issue a query to the database - with the only exception that in case of lazy loading `product.Discounts` will be loaded once from the database into memory. It will be loaded completely - no matter which LINQ operation or filter you perform.

If you want to perform filters or any queries on navigation collections without loading the collection completely into memory you must not access the navigation collection but create a query through the context, for instance in your example:

```
var chained = context.Entry(product).Collection(p => p.Discounts).Query()
                     .Where(d => d.CreationDate < DateTime.Now).Count();
```

This would not load the `Discounts` collection of the `product` into memory but perform a query in the database and then return a single number as result. The next query of this kind would go to the database again.

Answer (score 3):

In your examples above the Discounts collection should be populated by Ef the first time you access it.  The subsequent linq queries on the Discount collection should then be performed in  memory.  This will even include the last complex expression.

You can also use the Include method to make sure you are getting back associated collection first time.  example .Include("Discounts");

If your worried about performance I would recommend using SQL Profiler to have a look at what SQL is being executed.

Comment: @feanz - With EF 4.1 you can (and should) use `.Include(p => p.Discounts)` instead of the string-based method.

Comment: So when I compose a complex query as above, and the result is an int (say), then EF will pull the ENTIRE table(s)? I thought that it will issue smarter queries than that?

Comment: @Matt0 - How can EF issue smarter queries if you have already pulled the whole object before getting the counts? After that you are already in object space and your counts are none of EF's concern (except for lazy-loading the `Discounts` collection when accessed). If you just want the counts, you can write a smarter query. E.g. `context.Products.Where(p => p.Id == productId).Select(p => p.Discounts.Count()).Single()`. And I agree with @feanz - if you are concerned about performance, you can experiment with your queries and see what SQL is being generated for different cases.

Comment: Makes sense. Once you grab the collection, EF doesn't care. But what if I do this: `.Count(d=>d=...)` will that also load the entire object graph?

Comment: @Matt0: Yes, it will load the whole `Discounts` collection (not the whole object graph; if `Discount` has also navigation properties they won't be loaded until you access them.)

Comment: @Yakimych good point use the fluent api to get compile time checking