# Performance hit / Memory consumption when aggregating/filtering navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

Let us say I have the following set of classes :

```
public class MegaBookCorporation
{
    public int ID { get; private set}
    public int BooksInStock 
    {
        get
        {
            return Stores.Sum( x => x.BooksInStock)
        }
    }
    public virtual ICollection<MegaBookCorporationStore> Stores { get; set; }
}


public class MegaBookCorporationStore
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string BookStoreName { get; private get; }
    public virtual MegaBookCorporation ManagingCorporation { get; private set;}
    public int BooksInStock
    {
        get
        {
            return Books.Where( x=> !x.IsSold).Count();
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int IndividualBookTrackerID { get; private set; }
    public virtual MegaBookCorporationStore { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSold { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? SellingDate { get; private set;}
}
```

I had a discussion at work regarding the performance hit involved when retrieving the NumberOfBooks in a MegaBookCorporation. Two important facts :

1/ We're using EF 6 with Lazy Loading as suggested by the virtual keywords.

2/ Since every book is tracked individually the number of Book entries in the database will become great quickly. The table will likely have a size of hundreds of millions on the long run. We will perhaps be adding up to 100,000 books per day.

The opinion I supported is that the current implementation is fine and that we're not going to run into problems. My understanding is that a SQL statement would be generated to filter the collection when GetEnumerator is called.

The other suggestion made by my coworker is to cache the number of books. That means updating a field "int ComputedNumberOfBooks" whenever the AddBookToStock() or SellBook() methods would be called. This field would need to be repeated and updated in both the Store and Corporation classes. (Then of course we would need to take care of concurrency)

I know adding these fields wouldn't be a big deal, but I really feel bad about this idea. To me it looks like pre-engineering a problem that doesn't exist, and that in my opinion won't exist.

I decided to check again my claims with SO and found 2 contradicting answers :

[One saying that the whole Books collection would be pulled to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309151/are-navigation-properties-read-each-time-they-are-accessed-ef4-1), since ICollection only inherits from IEnumerable.
[The other saying the opposite : the navigation property will be treated as an IQueryable until it is evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342174/entity-framework-filtering-navigation-properties).(Why not since the property is wrapped by a proxy)

So here are my questions :

1- What is the truth ?

2- Even if the whole collection is referenced, don't you think that it's not a big deal since it would be an IEnumerable (low memory usage).

3- What do you think of the memory consumption / performance hit on this example, and what would be the best way to go ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The verdict

The truth is that with the properties you defined the whole collection of books is loaded. Here's why.

Ideally, you want to be able to do

```
var numberOfBooks = context.MegaBookCorporations
                           .Where(m => m.ID == someId)
                           .Select(m => m.BooksInStock)
                           .Single();
```

If EF would be able to turn this into SQL, you'd have a query that only returns an integer and loads no entities into memory whatsoever.

But, unfortunately, EF can't do this. It will throw an exception that there is no SQL translation for `BooksInStock`.

To circumvent this exception you *could* do:

```
var numberOfBooks = context.MegaBookCorporations
                           .Where(m => m.ID == someId)
                           .Single()
                           .BooksInStock;
```

This dramatically changes things. `Single()` draws one `MegaBookCorporation` into memory. Accessing its `BooksInStock` property triggers lazy loading of `MegaBookCorporation.Stores`. Subsequently, for each `Store` the complete `Books` collections are loaded. Finally, the LINQ operations (`x => !x.IsSold`, `Count`, `Sum`) are applied in memory.

So in this case, [the first link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6311315/861716) is correct. Lazy loading always loads complete collections. Once the collections are loaded, they will not be loaded again.

But the [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342591/861716) is correct too :).

As long as you manage to do everything in one LINQ statement that can be translated into SQL, the navigation properties and predicates will be evaluated in the database and no lazy loading will occur. But then you can't use the `BooksInStock` properties.

The only way to achieve this is by a LINQ statement like

```
var numberOfBooks = context.MegaBookCorporations
                           .Where(m => m.ID == someId)
                           .SelectMany(m => m.Stores)
                           .SelectMany(s => s.Books)
                           .Count();
```

This executes a pretty efficient query with one join and a `COUNT`, returning only the count.

So unfortunately, your key assumption...

> that a SQL statement would be generated to filter the collection when GetEnumerator is called.

Is not entirely correct. A SQL statement is generated, but not including the filter. With the numbers of books you mention this will cause severe performance and memory problems.

#### So what to do?

Something should be done if you need these counts frequently and you don't want to query them separately all the time. Your coworker's idea, a redundant `ComputedNumberOfBooks` field in the database could be a solution, but I share your objections.

Redundancy should be avoided at (nearly) all costs. The worst part is that it always requires a client application to keep both sides in sync. Or database triggers.

But talking about the database... If these counts are important and frequently queried, I would introduce a computed column `BooksInStock` in the `MegaBookCorporationStore` table. Its formula could simply do the count of books in store. Then you can add this computed column to your entity as a property that is marked as [`DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). No redundancy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive explanation. I'm a little sad because I was hoping that I could achieve that with a DDD approach (everything encapsulated in the class). It is an onion architecture, so in the Core Layer I can't use dbcontext. Therefore this reality is somehow breaking the architecture, since I will need to create an external object in charge of evaluating the internal "state" of this object

Comment: Well, forgot my previous comment, I'm a bit tired sorry. I read your comment again and there is no problem at all with what you suggest, the computed colomn would be part of the domain entity, and mapped with fluent api. What do you suggest to unit test it, looks like it will need to be populated manually

Comment: Take a nap brother :). I have a very explicit opinion about mocking a data layer: don't do it. Use integration tests. Of course you can create mock `MegaBookCorporation`s and so on, to test their behavior in pure unit tests. Just don't try to mock the process of getting these objects from the store.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the truth?

If you use `MegaBookCorporation.BooksInStock` to get the total number of books stored, all books are going to be loaded from the database. There is no way the query provider can generate an SQL expression for a property getter's body other than just fetching all the data and evaluating it in-memory.

> Even if the whole collection is referenced, don't you think that it's not a big deal since it would be an IEnumerable (low memory usage).

Yes, it's a big deal since it does not scale at all. It has nothing to do with the fact that it's `IEnumerable`. The problem is fetching all the data *before* evaluating `Count()`.

> What do you think of the memory consumption / performance hit on this example, and what would be the best way to go?

The memory consumption will grow with the number of books stored in the database. Since you only want to get their count, that's clearly a no-go. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#queryCount) you can see how to do it properly.